# NPM 7/8 is not installing peer dependencies

Tags: npm

I'm trying to build a repository/package for my personal ESLint config files. I have all of my configuration files built the way I would like, and now I am trying to install this package to test it.

In this scenario, I have two packages:

- `@me/eslint-config` is the package containing my ESLint config files.
- `test-package` is the package on/in which I am trying to install `@me/eslint-config`.

**When I try to install the `@me/eslint-config` package, peer dependencies are not installed, nor are they even mentioned during the installation.**

Both packages currently only reside locally on my machine, side-by-side, in the same directory:

```
<parent_dir>:
  - eslint-config
    - package.json
    - ...
  - test-package
    - package.json
    - ...
```

The `package.json` file for `@me/eslint-config` looks as follows:

```json
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.29.0"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "eslint": "8.18.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "39.3.3",
        "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.29.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

I am installing this package in `test-package` as follows:

```
$> cd /path/to/test-package
$> npm i ../eslint-config --save-dev
```

NPM properly installs all other dependencies, including the `@me/eslint-config` package itself, but does *not* install the `peerDependencies` of `@me/eslint-config`.

This is using NPM v8.1.0.

[This article](https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/) seems to suggest that NPM >7 installs peer dependencies automatically. This is obviously not working for me.

Things I have already tried that have not fixed the problem:

- Deleting `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` from `test-package` and reinstalling everything.
- Pinning all `peerDependencies` versions in `@me/eslint-config`.
- Adding all `peerDependencies` in `@me/eslint-config` as both `dependencies` *and* `peerDependencies` in `@me/eslint-config`.

**tl;dr** NPM isn't installing `peerDependencies`

Comment: Any luck of finding out why? I'm having the same issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on former version of npm and as you mention, npm ^8 now install peer dependencies.

But here could be ways of fining your problem

#### 1 : estlint is a devDependencies (A guess)

eslint should be `devDependencies` and not a `peerDependencies`.
Maybe npm doesn't accept you to install it then.

*I search a bit but couldn't find any real thread discussing about this*

That said, I wouldn't install it as dependencies since it will be pushed to your production build, what, I think, you do not want.

#### 2 : Being up to date

Try it with the latest version of npm

1. download the latest version of npm : `npm install -g npm@latest`
2. Delet `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` from test-package and reinstall everything. *as you did already*

#### 2 : allowJs

If eslint is an js package & you see it being installed in the `node_modules` folder.

1. Inside the `tsconfig.json` file, under the `compilerOptions` add `allowJs: true` and set `strict: false`

```js
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": false,
```

2. Close **all** your instance of vs-code
3. Restart & retry *(No need to remove the package-lock or so)*